# Have object return primitive value instead of self on get

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I know that the getter/setter methods of an object can be overwritten, but this requires specifying a property name. I'm looking for the following behaviour, which I could not find online:

```
let o = { a: '1', b: '2', (get: 'Hi!') };
console.log( o.a ) // 1
console.log( o.b ) // 2
console.log( o )   // 'Hi!'
```

Effectively have the object return something else when it is directly 'gotten'. I suppose another way to describe this is to have a default return value when a property is not accessed.

Comment: You can defined a `toString()` method, which will be used by `console.log()`. You can define `valueOf()`, which will be used if it needs to coerce it to a primitive value. But you can't define the value that's used in general.

Comment: There's no property to get there, other than the `o` binding from the lexical environment. But you can't tap into that mechanism as far as I know. Besides, if `o` were to resolve to "Hi" there wouldn't be any "a" property in the string object.

Comment: Maybe a hack with the "\_\_defineGetter\_\_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible.